# Execute Anonymous Error unexpected token 'test1'

Tags: execute-anonymous, anonymous

I am trying to insert a case using anonymous apex but I keep getting an error unexpected token 'test1'. Could somebody help to understand what's wrong with this code? In other threads, people pointed out that brackets are missing but I have all the needed characters.

```
Case test1 = new Case(BusinessHoursId=01m7000000007vPAAQ,
                      custom_field1__c='017a17f0-6404-42f4-8397-2d440d24e91d',
                      custom_field2__c='+44123456',
                      RecordTypeId=0125w000000BYNFAA4,
                      Status='Open',
                      Subject='INCOMING CALL ');
insert test1;
```

Error:

```
Line: 1, Column: 6
Unexpected token 'test1'.
```

Comment: Do you have a class in your org called "Case" or "Test"? If so, you need to rename that class.

Comment: No, but in this trailhead you can see it's possible to create contact in this why, so why not a case? https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_database/apex_database_dml?trailmix_creator_id=strailhead&trailmix_slug=prepare-for-your-salesforce-platform-developer-i-credential

Comment: You _can_ create a Case like this (as you can for any other SObject). The issue has something to do with the `Case test1` part rather than the `= new Case(...)` part. Accidentally shadowing the `Test` type (by having an Apex class saved in your org like `public class Test{ ...} ` is just the most common reason why you'd get an error like that. Please double check the classes in your org. If you still don't find any class named "Test", then try changing your variable name to not include the word "test".

Comment: I changed "test1" to "blabla" and it's the same :/

Comment: BTW, welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Moonpie !

Answer (score 5):

Put your `id` values in single quotes.

E.g., `BusinessHoursId='01m7000000007vPAAQ',`

---

For learning purposes, hard coding id values if fine. As you expand your knowledge and understanding, and get into "real world" scenarios, be sure to get any id values dynamically - via a SOQL query or other dynamic means.

Comment: Yes, I just discovered that, thanks, it worked!

Comment: _Moved entire contents of this comment as an addendum to the original answer._